# grok - how do you find a quoted string

Tags: regex, logstash, grok

I am trying to grab the output from an nginx log file and send it to logstash.

```
10.1.10.20 - bob [14/Feb/2014:18:57:05 +0000] “POST /main/foo.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1” 200 3653189 “-” “git/1.8.3.4 (Apple Git–47)”
```

Grock is able to find the first 3 words fine

```
10.1.10.20 - bob [14/Feb/2014:18:57:05 +0000]

%{IPV4:user_ip} - %{USERNAME:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\]
```

Grok is able to find the 3rd and 4th words fine

```
[14/Feb/2014:18:57:05 +0000] “POST /main/foo.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1”

\[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\] %{QUOTEDSTRING:request}
```

However when I combine them, and try to find all 4, grok says there are no results (using http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ for testing)

```
10.1.10.20 - bob [14/Feb/2014:18:57:05 +0000] “POST /main/foo.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1” 

%{IPV4:user_ip} - %{USERNAME:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\]  %{QUOTEDSTRING:request}
#not found
```

Anyone know how to get the quoted string in the above example?

I'm brand new to grok, so perhaps I'm not approaching this correctly.

**Update**

Interestingly if I use the following log line and then manually type in the url it does work

```
 bob 14/Feb/2014:18:57:05 +0000 "herp"
 #Once herp works, replace herp, with POST
 bob 14/Feb/2014:18:57:05 +0000 "POST"
 #Once POST works, keep expounding until the whole thing is in place
 autobuild 14/Feb/2014:18:57:05 +0000 "POST /main/builder.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to send the data to elasticsearch with the right type format (eg field time_local recognised as a date) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of posting to stack overflow identified the problem.

If you look carefully, the double quotes are parsed differently

```
"POST
```

vs

```
“POST
```

Manually typing in the double quote fixes the problem

Answer (score 3):

`"POST /main/builder.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1"` in pattern

"%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}"

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this expression for the cases where the log changes:

```
"%{WORD:verb}(?:| %{URIPATHPARAM:request})(?:| HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})"
```

it matches with:

```
"POST /main/builder.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1"
```

or

```
"POST /main/builder.git/git-upload-pack"
```

or

```
"POST"
```

try it.. ;)